# Substr in reverse direction

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to get the numbers from a numerics field (which is mostly 8 characters long) from the last digit back to 6 digits in reverse direction. E.g

```
2345678-- i want 345678
56789356--789356
```

I am using the below code:

```
sel SUBSTRING( LEVN010  from character_length(LEVN010)-5 for   6 )  FROM X.TABLE
```

But, this is not working. Any solution for this is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: What's the actual data type of `LEVN010`. Your code is correct for a Varchar.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `RIGHT` function:

```
SELECT RIGHT(LEVN010,6) FROM X.table
```

or use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LEVN010,-6) FROM X.table
```

Comment: try with `SUBSTRING(LEVN010,-6)` instead

Comment: Thanks fonfonx for your reply. It's working fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct for a VarChar column, but you don't need to specifiy `FOR`, it's optional and defaults to *until the end*:

```
SUBSTRING( LEVN010  from character_length(LEVN010)-5)
```

In TD15.10 the function `RIGHT` is supported:

```
RIGHT(LEVN010, 6)
```

If `LEVN010` is a fixed length `CHAR` there are probably trailing spaces and you need to `TRIM` them (I added the `FOR` back to get rid of the trailing spaces):

```
SUBSTRING( LEVN010  from character_length(TRIM(LEVN010))-5 FOR 6)
```

If `LEVN010`  is an `INTEGER` you better use `MOD`:

```
LEVN010 mod 1000000
```

Comment: Yes, you are right dieter..i casted the column to char and its working fine.
I am on TD 14, that's why Right is not working.
Will mod work on TD 14? i will have to test that probably on  monday.

Thanks a lot :)